# Fetch only the `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` for list using JSOM

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, jsom

I have a array of list names and I need to fetch `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` for each of the list. I can fetch the list objects. I need to know if there's any way where I can fetch only the `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` property for list. Is it possible? Will there be a performance improvement if all properties are fetched and if only a subset of them are fetched?

Below is my code.

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
var allLists = web.get_lists();

listnames = ["List 1", "List 2"]; // Array of list titles

var listArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < listnames.length; i++) {
    var oList = allLists.getByTitle(listnames[i]);
    listArray.push(allLists.getByTitle(listnames[i]));
    clientContext.load(listArray[i]);

    // Throws error
    //clientContext.load(listArray[i], "Include('ListItemEntityTypeFullName')"); 
}

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function (sender, args) {
    debugger;
    // Fetch the ListItemEntityTypeFullName by below command
    listArray[0].get_listItemEntityTypeFullName();
}, function (sender, args) {debugger});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. `Include` is used when loading a collection. When adding individual element (list or list item) we need to directly add the property name. Below is the updated code.

`clientContext.load(listArray[i], "ListItemEntityTypeFullName");`

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest two others roads :)

1 - If my assumption about why you need the `ListItemEntityTypeFullName` is correct, you may not need it anymore if you change your headers in your requests. You can replace `application/json;odata=verbose` by `application/json;odata=nometadata` and never have to send the type of list item.

2 - A Rest call would be really straight forward and would actually make a simpler code : `<site-uri>/_api/web/lists?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName&$filter=Title eq '<my-list-name' or Title eq '<my-other-list-name'` will return the following json object:

```
{
    value: Array<{ ListItemEntityTypeFullName: string }>
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am actually modifying existing code and need to fetch the values in JSOM itself. Plus, the no. lists in the `listnames` are going to be quite a few. So using JSOM to batch in a single request will be beneficial.